# grep words containing numbers

Tags: bash, sed

I have two strings

```
"Some Special xn39432n4 (foo bar)"
"Another thing goes 21 deer 14.5"
```

with `sed`, I want this output

```
xn39432n4
21 deer 14.5
```

means all space separated words containing numbers (from first to last occurrence) and non numerical words between them as well.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be sed? And, if so, which sed? What operating system are you using? Also, where are the strings? In a file? One per line? In a variable? In two separate variables?

Comment: And what should happen if a line has multiple matches? For example `foo 12 bar 12 xp8768bx 46`?

Comment: @terdon these are strings under different conditions that are returned in a loop.
the strings are changed, structure is same.

Also, as I mentioned in question, from first to last occurrence.

it should show `12 bar 12 xp8768bx 46`

Comment: Playing devil's advocate, does the word "one" constitute a number? Or do you mean (decimal) _digit_ when you use the word "number"?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like:

```
sed -n '
  s/\([^[:space:]]*[[:digit:]][^[:space:]]*\(.*[[:digit:]][^[:space:]]*\)\{0,1\}\).*/\
\1/
  s/.*\n//p' < your-file
```

Which matches a sequence of non-white`space` containing at least one `digit` optionally (`\{0,1\}`) followed by any sequence of characters followed by a digit and all the non-white`space`s following it.

That is captured in `\1`, we discard the characters after that (`.*`) and insert a newline before it, which we discard along with what precedes it in the next `s` command.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with GNU `grep`:

```
$ grep -oP '\w+[.\d]+\w+|[.\d]+\s+\w+\s+[.\d]+' file 
xn39432n4
21 deer 14.5
```

The two regular expressions are:

- `\w+[.\d]+\w+`: match one or more word characters (`\w+` matches a-z,A-Z and `_`), then one or more digits or `.` characters (`[.\d]+`), and then one or more word characters again (`\w+`).
- `[.\d]+\s+\w+\s+[.\d]+'`: match one or more digits or `.` characters (`[.\d]+`) then one or more whitespace characters (`\s+`), then one or more word characters again (`\w+`), then one or more whitespace characters and, finally, one or more numbers or `.` again.

Combined, these should match the two cases you described, although it's hard to know since you have only given two simple examples. And with the `-o` option to GNU `grep`, we print only the matching portion of each line.